# CSV file manipulation in Python, summing items relating to names in csv file

Tags: python, csv

Just a simple question from a newbie here, I have this `.csv` file that I have opened, everything works well up to here.

I then remove the header and I am left with the relevant information  names and associated values by this code:

```
with open('troms_il.csv', 'r') as data_file: 
    csv_data = csv.reader(data_file)

    # remove header from .csv
    next(csv_data)

    for line in csv_data:
        byer.append(f"{line[3]}, {line[2]}") # these are the towns, and money subsidised.
        print(byer)
```

and I get :

```
['BALSFJORD, 116613', 'Harstad, 181419', 'Harstad, 128886', 'Harstad, 22950', 'Harstad, 24948', 'IBESTAD, 614244', 'IBESTAD, 41361', 'IBESTAD, 42318', 'LAVANGEN, 262014', 'LENVIK, 34609', 'LENVIK, 592512', 'LENVIK, 842530', 'LENVIK, 590166', 'LENVIK, 563900', 'LENVIK, 405785', 'LENVIK, 154078', 'NORDREISA, 239942', 'SKJERVÃ˜Y, 57286', 'SKJERVÃ˜Y, 38789', 'STORFJORD, 56283', 'TROMSÃ˜, 155754', 'TROMSÃ˜, 114005', 'TROMSÃ˜, 300646', 'TROMSÃ˜, 94538']
```

in this example, all the names are towns, and the numbers represent the money they get in some subsidies. There are several duplicates of the towns with different money values assigned to them. I would like to know how to get the sum of money for each town here. I just cant figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

The csv file looks like this before doing anything to it:

```
Søker,Anleggsnr,Tildelt beløp,Kommune,Anlegg
Balsfjord Skytterlag,1933009401,116613,BALSFJORD,Nordkjosbotn skytebane 100m
HARSTAD KLATREKLUBB,1901000107,181419,Harstad,Hølogalandshallen - klatrevegg
HARSTAD KLATREKLUBB,1901000107,128886,Harstad,Hølogalandshallen - klatrevegg
Harstad Orienteringslag,1901001602,22950,Harstad,Kanebogen orienteringskart
Harstad Orienteringslag,1901001102,24948,Harstad,Medkila-Breivika orienteringskart
Ibestad Golfklubb,1917002601,614244,IBESTAD,Ibestad Golfklubb
Ibestad IL,1917003202,41361,IBESTAD,Sanitørbygg ørsand friluftspark
Ibestad IL,1917003203,42318,IBESTAD,Tursti ørsand friluftspark
Soløy Idrettsgruppe,1920001902,262014,LAVANGEN,Soløy lysløype
Botnhamn IL,1931000201,34609,LENVIK,Botnhamn lysløype
Finnsnes IL Allianse,1931000512,592512,LENVIK,Finnsnes IL Allianse utvidelse klubbhus
Finnsnes IL Allianse,1931000513,842530,LENVIK,Finnsnes IL Allianse ny garderobe
Finnsnes IL Allianse,1931000514,590166,LENVIK,Finnsnes IL Allianse lager
Gisund Skytterlag,1931007303,563900,LENVIK,Gisund skytterbane rehab bane
NMK Midt-Troms,1931011301,405785,LENVIK,Aspelund Motorsportanlegg
Senja ski,1931005103,154078,LENVIK,Rehabilitering av løype inkl. utskifte lysarmatur Senja ski
Nordreisa Rideklubb,1942002601,239942,NORDREISA,Nordreisa rideanlegg
ørviksand Bygdelag,1941000104,57286,SKJERVØY,Turstier i ørviksand 2
ørviksand Bygdelag,1941000103,38789,SKJERVØY,Turstier i ørviksand 1
Storfjord IL,1939000401,56283,STORFJORD,Brenna lysløype
Blømann IL,1902003905,155754,TROMSØ,Blømann Skatepark
Reinen IL,1902014303,114005,TROMSØ,Reinen nørmiljøanlegg
Tromsø Ryttersportklubb,1902007805,300646,TROMSØ,Tromsø Rideskole
Vikingur Rideklubb,1902024202,94538,TROMSØ,Tromsø Travbane
```

Comment: Please show the code you have used to read your data in.

Comment: Please, make more specific title. This is requirement for good SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the file a line at a time. You can use `strip()` to remove the newline at the end, and `split(',')` to give you a list of entries.

Next make use of a dictionary to hold your values for each town. If the dictionary already has an entry for the town, simple add the value to the existing value, else create a new town entry.

```
totals = {}

with open('input.csv', newline='', encoding='utf8') as f_input:
    next(f_input)  # skip the header

    for line in f_input:
        row = line.strip().split(',')
        town = row[3]
        value = int(row[2])

        if town in totals:
            totals[town] += int(value)
        else:
            totals[town] = int(value)

for town in sorted(totals.keys()): 
    print("{}  {}".format(town, totals[town]))
```

Giving you output starting as:

```
BALSFJORD  116613
Harstad  358203
IBESTAD  697923
```

Python also provides tools for doing this more easily such as the `csv` library for reading your file in automatically as lists. Also there is a `Counter()` which can be used to automatically total your values.

Using `csv` and `Counter()` could be done as follows:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv

totals = Counter()

with open('input.csv', newline='', encoding='utf8') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)  # skip the header

    for row in csv_input:
        totals[row[3]] += int(row[2])

for town in sorted(totals.keys()): 
    print("{}  {}".format(town, totals[town]))

print('LENVIK has', totals['LENVIK'])
```

Comment: Error in line 5, I get : ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Check your `input.csv` file to see if any of your lines are missing a `,` or if there is an empty line somewhere (e.g. the last line)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be missing any commas nor any empty spaces. say if I had the list that I posed in the question, is there no really simple way to ask for the town and the value coming after it in the .csv file?

Comment: I have updated my question, I think I was a bit unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are the best!

Comment: Just one final thing, If you look at the names of the towns, they look nice in the original .csv file, but when I print them through python the norwegian letters are not there and are replaced with weird letters. how do I tell python to write the norwegian letters? :)

Comment: You seem to be using Python 3. You should add an encoding to your file open.

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do that now that I am using with open() :o

Comment: just smashing! :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, lets read file to good data structure:

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(open("filename", "r") 
towns = list(csv_reader)[1:]
```

You also can get this for free with `csv` module.

Then we can construct structure with answers. It will be a `dict()`.

```
total_money = {}
for town, money in towns:
    current_money = total_money.get(town, 0)
    total_money[town] = current_money + money
```

Also there is more intuitve solution it functional style.

```
def town_money_list(current_town):
    return [money for town, money if town == current_town]

total_money = {town: sum(town_money_list(town)) for town, money in towns}
```

Comment: So, for my  csv file, can I still use the with open('troms_il.csv', 'r') as data_file:
    csv_data = csv.reader(data_file)

Comment: and where in your code here is the actual list that I have opened, I am so terrible at this, it is quite baffling.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsen I changed my code according to what you have done so far. Hope now it is clear. You can mark my question as accepted, if it solved your problem.

Comment: cant get this code to work, its giving me : too many values to unpack, (expected 2) when I do the dict.

Comment: I have updated my question, I think I was a bit unclear.